# google form how to edit drop down list of date choices

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

hi i want to make a form for doing appointment in my shop, there is a question for customer to choose the reservation date and i want to make it Day + 1.

I succeed in making it but the date format is too long, i only want DAY, DD-MM-YYYY not the time and etc. So how to set the date format only DAY,DD-MM-YYYY? thanks

this is the script code:

```
    var ssID = "1hil07Z2wvTXH1szX9bNfPKVLDQVO36ACQFGOU6_VUI0";
var formID="1SD5BenAnNxNz-wtw0YPut6YdTf7a62zHn_z3VrTdTUU";

var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("DATA");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){

var labels = wsData.getRange(1,1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

labels.forEach(function(label,i){
 var options =  wsData
 .getRange(2, i+1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1)
 .getValues()
 .map(function(o){return o[0]})
 .filter(function(o){return o !== ""});
//Logger.log(options);
updateDropDownUsingTitle(label,options);

});

}



function updateDropDownUsingTitle(title,values) {
var title = "Tanggal Penjemputan";
var items = form.getItems();
var titles = items.map(function(item){
return item.getTitle();

});
var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
var item = items[pos];
var itemID = item.getId();

updateDropdown(itemID,values);
}

function updateDropdown(id,values) {

var item = form.getItemById(id);
item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}
```

this is the form
[image]

and this is the spreadsheet for the dropdown choices

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) to format the `date` (`getValues` give you the `date` objects), or simply use [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) to get what you see on the spreadsheet.